# Solving an integral with from compound distribution of two Normal Distributions with a Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals

I'm looking to solve an integral that arises when trying to find the probability density of a random variable that is distributed uniformly as $\mathcal{U}(a,b)$, but whose endpoints, $(a,b)$, are themselves distributed by the same normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma)$, where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation.

The integral to be done is 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi \sigma^2}\iint_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{|b-a|} \text{rect} \left[ \frac{x - (a+b)/2}{b-a} \right] \exp \left[ - \frac{(a^2 + b^2)}{2 \sigma^2} \right]\, \text{d} a \text{d} b,
\end{align}

where the rect$(x)$ function is defined as 1 when $|x|<1/2$ and 0 otherwise. Note here that it does not matter if $a<b$ or $b<a$.

This integral looks solvable, but organizing the limits and such may prove to be tedious. Numerically, it looks like the solution should itself look similar to another Gaussian.

Any ideas on how to solve or set up the limits of this integral?